# No such module 'SDWebImage'

Tags: ios, swift2, cocoapods, sdwebimage

I installed `SDWebImage` using `CocoaPods`.

My podfile was as it is written in the https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
```

when I import `SDWebImage` it says

> No such module 'SDWebImage'

my `Xcode` version is: Version `7.2.1`

Comment: Are you opening your Project or the Workspace? The workspace will include the SDWebImage pod. You need to build the workspace for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't build. it seems it is working now.

Comment: Hi @tmac99  I have did the same thing, but it showing linker error while try to run workspace. Have you faced it?

Answer (score 8):

Use the new `<YourProject>.xcworkspace` instead of `<YourProject>.xcodeproj`.

The `xcworkspace` contains your `project` and your `pods` after `pod install`.

Answer (score 2):

Just build your project before and after importing any new pods in your code

Answer (score 1):

> Add `-ObjC` in `Other Linker Flags`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to podfile like

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment the next line when you want all Pods as static framework
# use_modular_headers!
pod 'SDWebImage', :modular_headers => true
```

or

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked uncommenting this line in podfile:

#use_frameworks! ->  use_frameworks!