# No such module 'SDWebImage' using pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, sdwebimage

This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899890/no-such-module-sdwebimage) But no answers work for me. I have tried all the ways which are mentioned below.

1. Open project using .xcworkspace
2. Deleted all the pod related file from project and again pod install even updated the cocoa pods.
3. Added $(inherited) flag in Other Linker Flags. and -ObjC also, so it may find path from pod framework.
4. Added bridging file to import SDWebImage.
5. Deep clean, build every time and restart the project.

I am checking all scenario since 4 to 5 hours but I am not getting the exact reason why this is happening.

Below is my Pod file.

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'ProjectName' do
     pod 'Alamofire'
     pod 'SDWebImage'
end
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes xcode shows error but still build will be succeed .. pls try to build. I know its weird but atleast try once.

Comment: Can you please share your pod file

Comment: Yes, please show the pod file. Sometimes you need to remove the `.xcworkspace` as well. Then execute `pod install` to recreate the workspace file.

Comment: @EmreÖnder I have added pod file in question.

Comment: What is your minimum supported iOS version? 12.0?

Comment: @Raptor as I mentioned I have removed pod related file and setting from project and also tried pod deintegrate.

Comment: @EmreÖnder yes. its 12.0

Comment: @user9970928 Use `pod update` command in terminal

Comment: @PratikSodha I do it around 20 times.

Comment: Remove Podfile.lock and Pods folder and try with `pod install` command. Also remove Derived data.

Comment: @PratikSodha did it all but was no success..I have created new project from from scratch and installed pod it worked. Its weird... but works. Thanks all you guys for the time and support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me many times try these steps:

-> Try cleaning your project

OR

-> Restart your `Xcode`

OR

-> If you doing a new `project` setup than try again new `project` again

1. delete your `workspace`
2. again create your new workspace with `pods` installing from fresh
3. try to `rebuild`

3rd option could work as this happens many times when `search paths` are not getting in `build settings` of your project

Comment: I have tried to created new project as you mentioned in 3rd option. Now all works fine. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 9):

`SDWebImage` is a Swift pod depending on Objective-C, which is different than `Alamofire`, and needs one extra step:

- For `CocoaPods 1.5.0+` (and `Xcode 9+`):
  Add `:modular_headers => true` to the line of package name, like:

```
# For CocoaPods after 1.5.0
target 'ProjectName' do
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SDWebImage', :modular_headers => true
end
```

- For earlier versions:
  Add or uncomment `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile, like

```
# For CocoaPods before 1.5.0
target 'ProjectName' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
end
```

Finally, to apply the change, please

1. Close Xcode
2. Run `pod update` in the project folder
3. Open the `.xcworkspace` file in Xcode again.

Reference:
[SDWebImage Installation Guide](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/Installation-Guide)
[CocoaPods 1.5.0 — Swift Static Libraries](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/)

Comment: Holy shit you absolute LEGEND...using :modular_headers was the key for me, after a day and a half of struggle.  Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 1):

Start Fresh

1. Open terminal
2. Drag Path Of your Project
3. Create Podfile add the required dependencies
4. pod install
5. Open Workspace
6. Locate SDWebImage.framework in products including support files
7. DO Show in Finder for SDWebImage.framework. copy the framework and use it any where

Comment: Did this, no luck :(

Comment: Located in Other linker flags, Search path and framework path.

Comment: with what i understood you have found the file with name SDWebImage.framework. Right? if yes add that in linked Frameworks and libraries and embedded binaries

Comment: In existing project there must be some build settings path or xcconfig file setting. so I created new project with same files.. Now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

go to your workspace's Edit Scheme > Build > select check both Build Options.

Make sure "Find Implicit Dependencies" is checked.