# No such module 'SDWebImage' using pod swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, sdwebimage

This question is already asked here [No such module 'SDWebImage' using pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683959/no-such-module-sdwebimage-using-pod) But no answers work for me. I have tried all the ways which are mentioned below.

1. Open project using .xcworkspace
2. Added bridging file to import SDWebImage.
3. clean, build every time and restart the project.
4. Restart xCode
5. Re-install Pods

[image: View Controller]

[image: Pod file]

Comment: Can you import the other pods without errors?

Comment: where you able to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try clean DerivedData.

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-delete-derived-data-and-clean.html

If nothing works, you can look at Swift Package Manager install

> Installation with Swift Package Manager (Xcode 11+)

https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage#installation-with-swift-package-manager-xcode-11

Answer (score 1):

Start by deleting the import statement. Given that you have done `pod install`, build your code. After successfully building the code, please try to add the import statement.

This is a long shot, may help you.