# Suddenly can no longer compile - No such module 'SDWebImage'

Tags: swift, xcode

So suddenly my project stopped working and I have no idea why and I'm running out of ideas.

I've found some blogs [1](https://andresalla.com/en/fixing-virtual-filesystem-overlay-file-all-product-headers-yaml-not-found-error/) [2](https://steipete.com/posts/couldnt-irgen-expression/) and similar requests [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683959/no-such-module-sdwebimage-using-pod) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907319/no-such-module-sdwebimage-using-pod-swift-5) for help but nothing seems to work for me. I may be doing something wrong though.

running xcode 13.4.1

I've got 4 distinct errors

```
Command EmitSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
```

```
error: accessing build database "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-btdfdbatbdurmeawknwdwmjrqpsw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db": disk I/O error
```

```
Virtual filesystem overlay file '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-btdfdbatbdurmeawknwdwmjrqpsw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App DEV.build/all-product-headers.yaml' not found
```

```
/Users/myuser/myapp-ios-app/App/UI/Feed/FeedVC/FeedVC.swift:11:8: No such module 'SDWebImage'
```

I believe the EmitSwiftModule is related with not being able to handle the pod therefore causing the issue in the "all-product-headers.yaml" which is generated to fetch all the pods headers?

So assuming that all things in derived date are as they should be (because i've deleted it) I tried to focus on why is the pod no longer compiling. To my co-worker is working fine. Maybe he will have the same issue if he deletes the derivedData? Maybe we are using some older version files?

Some things I've tried:

- clean the project
- reset pods cache
- delete derived data folder
- update the pods
- clean xcode preferences
- for this pod they say we should add :modular_headers => true in pod file
- re download the project clean to another folder
- instead of cocoapods use the package manager for SDWebImage
- due "all-product-headers.yaml" issue i read here that i could just add a header to my project

I've tried to create a project from scratch and just use the same pods and the project seems to run fine. But this is not a solution.

Can someone please help me? Any ideas?

Comment: Is the corresponding library properly linked in "frameworks and libraries" window found in project -> general tab?

Comment: yes, but i think is something related with references, because once i remove "import sdwebimage" it started complaining on other imports

Comment: So, to whoever might come here... Seems something is wrong when using the derived data folder specifically for this project... no idea what... but I've ended up by switching to another folder and the project was compiling successfully... it's not a solution but it works for now.
 
On another note, on the day previous to the issue started I had an update on Google drive. I don't use google drive nor have an account to sync to... but if this was messing around with the folder by sync stuff it might be related to the issue

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Try making it an answer and accept it . 